# Fast data entry form something like org-agenda or magit

Tags: org-agenda

I would like to use emacs to enter data -- to start with, essentially a set of numeric responses to a list of questions.  The questions will usually be the same every day, but will change slowly over time.

I want the data to be recorded as plain text, but to use a more constrained interface than just typing plain text, so that it's faster to enter the data and less error-prone.  For example:

- I would like j and k to move up and down between fields
- I don't want to have to enter say evil's insert state in order to enter numeric values
- I want the names of the questions to be automatically filled in and non-editable

The only code I've seen like this in emacs is org-agenda -- org-habit in particular is quite similar to what I have in mind.  However, org is a rather big code base, and though great software, not always the most exemplary elisp code in my book.  magit has a somewhat similar approach to interaction, though it happens not to have any UI you'd be likely to describe as "data entry".

Does anything like this already exist?  How can I go about implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1):

[The Emacs Widget Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/widget/index.html) might just be what you are looking for. Emacs' Custom interface is built on top of `widget` and while that isn't exactly the same as "data entry" it comes much closer than say Magit (which I would say has *nothing* to do with data entry).